# How to deal with long Full Garbage Collection cycle in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

We inherited a system which runs in production and started to fail every 10 hours recently. Basically, our internal software marks the system that is has failed if it is unresponsive for a minute. We found that our problem that our Full GC cycles last for 1.5 minutes, we use 30 GB heap. Now the problem is that we cannot optimize a lot in a short period of time and we cannot partition of our service quickly but we need to get rid of 1.5 minutes pauses as soon as possible as our system fails because of these pauses in production. For us, an acceptable delay is 20 milliseconds but not more. What will be the quickest way to tweak the system? Reduce the heap to trigger GCs frequently? Use System.gc() hints? Any other solutions? We use Java 8 default settings and we have more and more users - i.e. more and more objects created.

Some GC stat

[image]

Comment: Try one of the other GC algorithms if your JVM supports them.

Comment: Does the Full GC actually succeed in freeing much space?

Answer (score 3):

There is no one-size-fits-all magic bullet solution to your problem: you'll need to have a good handle on your application's allocation and liveness patterns, and you'll need to know how that interacts with the specific garbage collection algorithm you are running (function of version of Java and command line flags passed to `java`).

Broadly speaking, a Full GC (that succeeds in reclaiming lots of space) means that lots of objects are surviving the minor collections (but aren't being leaked).  Start by looking at the size of your Eden and Survivor spaces: if the Eden is too small, minor collections will run very frequently, and perhaps you aren't giving an object a chance to die before its tenuring threshold is reached.  If the Survivors are too small, objects are going to be promoted into the Old gen prematurely.

GC tuning is a bit of an art: you run your app, study the results, tweak some parameters, and run it again.  As such, you will need a benchmark version of your application, one which behaves as close as possible to the production one but which hopefully doesn't need 10 hours to cause a full GC.

As you stated that you are running Java 8 with the default settings, I believe that means that your Old collections are running with a Serial collector.  You might see some very quick improvements by switching to a Parallel collector for the Old generation (-XX:+UseParallelOldGC).  While this might reduce the 1.5 minute pause to some number of seconds (depending on the number of cores on your box, and the number of threads you specify for GC), this will not reduce your max pause to to 20ms.

Comment: thanks, I updated my post with image of our heap stat if you can check that?

Comment: By the way, you recommend to use UseParallelOldGC but why not UseConcMarkSweepGC as it should be faster for us?

Comment: @Mark - CMS might be faster, or it might not.  The "best" GC is highly dependent on your particular application and workload (and also what "best" means in your context).  The only way is to test.

Comment: thanks, here is our GC log 65154.265: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 2765438K->0K(8924160K)] [ParOldGen: 24328402K->22508332K(24466944K)] 27093841K->22508332K(33391104K), [Metaspace: 78790K->78163K(83968K)], 80.8081759 secs] [Times: user=147.73 sys=0.68, real=80.81 secs]  I think we already using Parallel Collector

Comment: @Mark - The text "24 328 402K->22 508 332K" means that GC didn't' actually succeed in collecting much of the space in the old gen: the size of the used space in the old gen was reduced from 24 gigs to 22 gigs.  This either means that you are legitimately running out of memory, or that there is a leak somewhere.  No GC algorithm or tuning will help this problem!

Comment: thanks Dan, but if I give more memory, Full GC will run longer, isn't it?

Comment: @Mark - There is a trade off, the more memory you give, the longer it will take for a GC to occur, but the longer that GC will run.  If you have a "restart window", and can give the app enough memory to make it to that restart window then this might be really useful.  Otherwise, you'll need to figure out if there is a leak (and solve it), or figure out how to use less memory.  A good first tool is the "jmap" utility - you can use it to dump a histogram of all the live objects on the heap.

Comment: I'd think there's some memory leak there. Or perhaps you save a lot of data in "caches"? Your old gen contains a lot of objects and apparently, many of those objects live for a long time since Full GC wasn't able to reclaim much memory.
Definitely, try to take a heap dump (via jmap, jcmd, etc.) and analyze it (standard profilers, Eclipse MAT, etc.). Then check which objects take most space and see if you find anything suspicious.

Comment: And please, update your post to include additional details mentioned in comments

Answer (score 3):

You have a lot of retained data. There is a few options which are worth considering.

- increase the heap to 32 GB, this has little impact if you have free memory. Looking again at your totals it appears you are using 32 GB rather than 30 GB, so this might not help.
- if you don't have plenty of free memory, it is possible a small portion of your heap is being swapped as this can increase full GC times dramatically.
- there might be some simple ways to make the data structures more compact. e.g. use compact strings, use primitives instead of wrappers e.g. `long` for a timestamp instead of `Date` or `LocalDateTime`. (`long` is about 1/8th the size)
- if neither of these help, try moving some of the data off heap. e.g. Chronicle Map is a ConcurrentMap which uses off heap memory can can reduce you GC times dramatically. i.e. there is no GC overhead for data stored off heap. How easy this is to add highly depends on how your data is structured.

I suggest analysing how your data is structured to see if there is any easy ways to make it more efficient.

Comment: thanks Peter, didn't get why heap increase have little impact? Will you be able to provide detaled answer? Because, this is the fastest solution for us versus others.

Comment: @Mark whether you use a 30 GB or 32 GB heap doesn't slow the JVM provided there is free memory. By comparison a 33 GB heap will be slower as it has to use 64 bit references. Having a larger heap will reduce the time between GCs and a larger young space could reduce the amount of premature promotion.

Comment: @Mark in any case, you should consider that you can reduce memory usage significantly with small changes esp if this hasn't been looked at in the past. You need to analyse the memory usage profile e.g. with flight recorder to make an assessment. Most of the work is investigation rather than changes to the code. However you can see a dramatic reduction is many cases.

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, it was due to a memory leak caused by a static variable eating up memory. I would go through all recent code changes and look for any possible memory leaks.

Comment: We did analysis but there is no leaks. We just have a traffic growth and more garbage generated

Comment: It's also possible there's a server config issue, but IDK What your servers are like.